# How to extend Pandas with custom IO functions?

Tags: python, pandas, setuptools

I have written some functions to read data from a custom file format and convert it into a pandas data frame. I would like to be able to access this from within the pandas namespace, i.e, after installing my package with pip, I should be able to

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_custom("/my/file")
```

My questions are:

1. Is this even possible?
2. How would I implement this?

P.S: I remember that pandas support for feather used to work this way until it officially became a part of `pandas.io`. I can't seem to find the code for it now.

Answer (score 1):

Just create your own class, which should inherit from the `DataFrame` class and implement the `to_custom()` method.

Simple example:

```
class MyDF(pd.DataFrame):
    def to_custom(self, filename, **kwargs):
        # put your deserializer code here ...
        return self.to_csv(filename, **kwargs)
```

Test:

```
In [16]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3), columns=list('abc'))

In [17]: mdf = MyDF(df)

In [18]: type(mdf)
Out[18]: __main__.MyDF

In [19]: mdf.to_custom('d:/temp/res.csv', index=False)
```

Result:

```
In [20]: from pathlib import Path

In [21]: print(Path('d:/temp/res.csv').read_text())
a,b,c
0,1,2
3,4,5
6,7,8
```

Comment: This would work well for a write method, but it doesn't really answer my question about a read method. I would like to be able to to call my read function as `pd.read_custom`.

Comment: @nihil0, well, if you want to call it `pd.function_name()` - you would need to change the Pandas source code and you would need to do it for __each__ Pandas release that you are using... ;)

Comment: It seems the way feather worked was different from what I had thought. Looks like the only way to usurp the pandas namespace is to monkey-patch (not recommended), or as you said, extend the pandas source code.